How to find out the web-to-lead limit?
As per the documentation, there is a 500 per 24 hour rolling limit of how many leads can be created via the web-to-lead functionality.
Although the default lead creator is notified via email if this limit has been exceeded, is there a way to identify the limit via the Limits class?

The Limits class only handles per-transaction limits, like CPU time or Heap Size. There are other limits you can access with the Limits REST API call, but this unfortunately doesn't include things like Web-to-Lead or Web-to-Case. In the meantime, vote on this Idea.
